# how to put the string with in href (<a href=>Demo</a>) by using escape sequences?

Tags: java, escaping

I have the following code snippet and i am trying add string demoString to href.

```
String demoString = "/helio/demo";
String demoStrUrl = "<a href=demoString ><h3 class="+"demoDetails" +">Details</h3></a>"
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
String demoString = "/helio/demo";
String demoStrUrl = "<a href=\"" + demoString + "\"><h3 class=\"demoDetails\">Details</h3></a>";
```

Note that if you want to add a `"` sign within the String, you have to escape it with `\`

Answer (score 0):

You have to append String variables as an object using `+` only. Otherwise it would again be handled like a fixed String and not your defined variable.

```
String demoString = "/helio/demo";
String demoStrUrl = "<a href=\""+demoString+"\" ><h3 class=\"demoDetails\">Details</h3></a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

First escape the quote of demoString:

```
String demoString = "\"/helio/demo\"";
```

Then add it to `demoStrUrl` using `+` operator:

```
String demoStrUrl = "<a href="+demoString+" ><h3 class.....
```

To facilitate with escaping HTML you can look into the apache commons [`StringEscapeUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html) class.